# Porting C struct to C#

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

I'm Porting C code to C# and I have some doubts.

Consider this structure:

```
typedef struct
{
  uint32_t       w;
  uint32_t       h;
  uint32_t       f_cc;
  uint32_t       st;
  unsigned char *pl[4];
  int32_t        strd[4];
  void         (*done)(void *thisobj);
  void          *e_cc;
  uint32_t       rsrvd2;
  uint32_t       rsrvd3;
} f_tt;
```

I've done this and it does not work (probably because it's wrong :-/ ):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct f_tt
{
    public uint w;
    public uint h;
    public uint f_cc;
    public uint st;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public Byte[] pl;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public int[] strd;
    public delegate void done(IntPtr thisobj);
    public delegate void e_cc();
    public uint rsrvd2;
    public uint rsrvd3;
}
```

Can someone advise me how to do this i c#?

```
  void         (*done)(void *thisobj);
  void          *e_cc;
```

Thank you!

Comment: If it ever involves pointers, you should be using `IntPtr` in most cases.

Comment: Can you give some information about what the desired semantics of those `byte*`s in `pl` are? In particular if they point to a single byte, a null terminates string, some fixed size array,... | hmm. Guess those are 4 pointers to one color component each

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before we come to the delegates, I suspect that you are wrong to pack the struct. It's very unusual to do so. Only do that if you find the pack `#pragma` in the C code.

The `e_cc` field is not a function pointer. It's just a void pointer. In C# that is `IntPtr`.

The `pl` member is an array of 4 pointers. I'm not quite sure what they contain, but for sure you can marshal that like this:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
public IntPtr[] pl;
```

That leaves you with manual intervention to populate the array, or read its contents. It's possible that could be done by the marshaller, but without knowing the semantics of the interop, I can't say how to do that.

As for `done`, you should declare the delegate outside the struct. Like this:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void doneDelegate(IntPtr thisobj);
```

Here I am assuming that the calling convention is `cdecl` since there's nothing in the C code to say otherwise.

Putting it all together you have:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void doneFunc(IntPtr thisobj);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct f_tt
{
    public uint w;
    public uint h;
    public uint f_cc;
    public uint st;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public IntPtr[] pl;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public int[] strd;
    public doneDelegate done;
    public IntPtr e_cc;
    public uint rsrvd2;
    public uint rsrvd3;
}
```

Comment: Is the `pl` part correct? Looks like an array of 4 pointers to me.

Comment: IIRC, pointers are 8-byte in x64, so it seems that you're assuming that this code only runs on x86? (btw why don't use `byte` instead of `Byte`)

Comment: @AlvinWong I did not assume the code runs on x86 only. The code in Q uses Byte. I copied.

Comment: @user2291568 Are you sure? It might compile now, but my first version had an error in the translation of `pl`. CodeInChaos spotted that where I missed it. I think the current version of the code in the answer is accurate.

Comment: Yes David, you are right! It is working because a saw what CodesInChaos said! ;)