# sizeof() not taking my type name

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, struct, sizeof

I have a `struct` in my program for which I need to use the size to allocate managed memory for an instance of the struct. I've tried using [sizeof()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf(v=vs.100).aspx), but I get the following errors:

`Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type('StatusType')`

`'StatusType' does not have a predefined size, therefore sizeof can only be used in an unsafe context (consider using System.RunTime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf)`

Why is this happening? I'm using `sizeof()` correctly (on a type name). Using `Marshal.SizeOf()` would be incorrect because I'm not working with unmanaged code. What is the correct approach?

My `struct` is as follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct StatusType 
{
    ushort VehID;         
    ushort Location;        
    ushort Destination;     

    // Note: the way Intel Byte-swaps, the 16-bit definition below is "backwards" from the way a human may view things
    [FlagsAttribute]
    enum firstByte : uint
    {
        Battery = 2,           
        Reverse = 1,           
        LiveDINO = 1,         
        ActuallyCharging = 1,  
        BothLoads = 2,         
        AttemptingToCharge = 1 
    };

    [FlagsAttribute]
    enum secondByte : uint
    {
        Manual = 1,             
        AutoReady = 1,
        Released = 1,
        Unused1 = 1,           
        CVS = 3,              
        RequestStop = 1         
    };
    // End byte-swap note

    [FlagsAttribute]
    enum thirdByte : ushort { CmdParsingError = 8 }; 
    [FlagsAttribute]
    enum fourthByte : ushort { Error = 8 };       

    [FlagsAttribute]
    enum fifthByte : ushort
    {
        TagReadCycles = 4,                           
        Unused = 4
    };

    [FlagsAttribute]
    enum sixthByte : ushort { Condition = 8 };       

    byte[] Tag;
    ushort CCUInputs;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct union
    {
        ushort ShortCheckSum;   
        ushort DestParam;       
    }

    ushort CurrentLiftHeight;
    ushort PCLInputs;

    [FlagsAttribute]
    enum seventhByte : ushort
    {
        Unused2 = 8             
    };

    [FlagsAttribute]
    enum eigthByte : ushort
    {
        BatteryVoltage = 6,    
        Unused3 = 2
    };

    ushort LongCheckSum;       
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [sizeof() structures not known. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048540/sizeof-structures-not-known-why)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess `byte[] Tag;` is your problem. Take a look at [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx).

Especially this sentence:

> One-dimensional arrays of blittable types, such as an array of integers. However, a type that contains a variable array of blittable types is not itself blittable.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. So how would I still use `byte[] Tag` in my struct? I'm not allowed to initialize an instance, which was what I originally wanted to do. C++ would allow something like `unsigned char Tag[6];`, but I changed it to `byte[] Tag;` because it wouldn't allow the first option.

Comment: Which data originally do you want to marshal to .net?

Comment: As far as `Tag` goes, I want to marshal an `unsigned char` array of 6 elements. I've tried this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065110/porting-c-struct-to-c-sharp), but `sizeof()` still gives me the same issues.

Comment: Does it have to be a struct? Have you tried to make a class out of it? And use `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]  public char[] Tag;`

Comment: I'm still using a struct, but implementing the above ^ strategy seems to do the trick for now. I'm also using `Marshal.SizeOf()`. I'm hoping that it will still work okay with C# .Net