# Using a C struct in C#

Tags: c#, c++

I am trying to port a windows-only USB driver to Linux by switching from hid.dll and other windows-only-stuff to the cross-platform [hidapi](https://github.com/signal11/hidapi).

hidapi.h contains the following definitions:

```
struct hid_device_info {
    char *path;
    unsigned short vendor_id;
    unsigned short product_id;
    wchar_t *serial_number;
    unsigned short release_number;
    wchar_t *manufacturer_string;
    wchar_t *product_string;
    unsigned short usage_page;
    unsigned short usage;
    int interface_number;
    struct hid_device_info *next;
};
```

and

```
struct hid_device_info HID_API_EXPORT * HID_API_CALL hid_enumerate(unsigned short vendor_id, unsigned short product_id);
```

Please see the link above for the code with comments.

The driver is written in C#, so I would like to connect to the hidapi library and use these directly. I have managed to get access to hid_enumerate by doing this:

```
[DllImport ("/usr/local/lib/libhidapi-hidraw.so.0")]
internal static extern IntPtr hid_enumerate (ushort vendor_id, ushort product_id);
```

Calling hid_enumerate later then gives me a pointer. However, I am unsure how to proceed from here. I would like to turn this into a LinkedList of hid_device_info objects, or some other structure in C#.

I am quite new to C#, but have a lot of programming experience.
Could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Here's a pointer for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065110/porting-c-struct-to-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing. I made a struct in C# like this:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct hid_device_info {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public String path;
        public ushort vendor_id;
        public ushort product_id;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public String serial_number;
        public ushort release_number;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public String manufacturer_string;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public String product_string;
        public ushort usage_page;
        public ushort usage;
        public int interface_number;
        public IntPtr next;
    };
```

and when calling hid_enumerate, I did this to turn the pointer into an instance of the struct:

```
        List<hid_device_info> list = new List<HidDeviceManager.hid_device_info> ();

        IntPtr pDev = hid_enumerate (0, 0);

        while (pDev != IntPtr.Zero) {
            hid_device_info dev = new hid_device_info();
            dev = (hid_device_info)Marshal.PtrToStructure (pDev, typeof(hid_device_info));
            list.Add (dev);

            pDev = dev.next;
        }
```

It works well.